# How to make clone of class instance?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, instance

So I have this class:

```
class Test
{
    private int field1;
    private int field2;

    public Test()
    {
        field1 = // some code that needs
        field2 = // a lot of cpu time
    }

    private Test GetClone()
    {
        Test clone = // what do i have to write there to get Test instance
                     // without executing Test class' constructor that takes
                     // a lot of cpu time?
        clone.field1 = field1;
        clone.field2 = field2;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

The code pretty much explains itself. I tried to solve that and came up with this:

```
private Test(bool qwerty) {}

private Test GetClone()
{
    Test clone = new Test(true);
    clone.field1 = field1;
    clone.field2 = field2;
    return clone;
}
```

I havent tested it out though, but am I doing it right? Is there better way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, one would write a copy constructor for this:

```
public Test(Test other)
{
     field1 = other.field1;
     field2 = other.field2;
}
```

If you want, you can also add a Clone method now:

```
public Test Clone()
{
     return new Test(this);
}
```

Going even further, you could have your class implement `ICloneable`. This is the default interface a class should implement if it supports cloning of itself.

Comment: Am I missing something here? The title says "without executing constructor" and none of the code samples seems to implement the requirement. Either requirement needs change or the code.

Comment: @foxneSs It's indeed quite simple here, but bear in mind than cloning *can* be more complicated as soon as you've got **object fields** instead of `int`s. The distinction is irrelevant here, but in general there are *shallow copies* (copy the references only of fields) and *deep copies* (clone all the objects which are references by fields too), and particularly the latter might be a bit of work to create. However, there's no need to worry about all this right here and now.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid i didnt understand you much but i have to say i hate reference types so much. same with python's immutable types. they make problems out of nowhere.

Comment: @foxneSs: sorry I was not trying to be net police. I see SO as a great source of solutions. Hence I thought if title was fixed, others might be benefited too.

Answer (score 3):

While there's an answer, which solves OP problem, I'll add another one, which answers the question. To get instance of class without executing its constructor, use [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var uninitializedObject = (MyClass)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(MyClass));
```

Comment: I changed title because it was wrong, sorry. I thought I needed what you gave but in fact I just needed to make clone